# Shared jwt token with cross domain apps i built

Tags: angular, jwt, single-sign-on, access-token

I built 3 app in angular with NodeJS backend all apps use the same db and backend apis.

1. Login App: asks for user creds and after 2FA verification api returns access and refresh token. deployed at for example https://www.loginApp.com
2. admin App: handles admin stuff create user handle permission. contains bunch of forms for inserting data into database. needs access token to append to header for api calls. deployed at for example https://www.adminApp.com
3. Another App: similar to admin app, contains different forms saves data in db.deployed at for example https://www.anotherApp.com

... there are bunch of more apps in the pipeline for future development.

Please dont ask me why i have this design but this is how it is and its not going to change. client is very insistent that each app will be deployed on a separate domain.

Application Flow:
User lands on login app and once logged in token and refresh token are save in local storage on loginApp and redirected to admin or another app depending on environment variable.

on admin app the user should not be asked for creds because the user is logged in. one way to do this is to pass token and refresh token via querystring to admin app when redirected after login and admin app saves it in its own localstoage and use this token(this is currently implemtned and working fine)

the problem is that its not recommended to pass the token via querystring. another option is to use the login app iframe on admin app that posts message it works for same domain different post like localhost:4200 and localhost:4201 but when i deployed the code on separate domain its was not retrieving the local storage keys. it always returned undefined.

Now im out of ideas.please help

Comment: localstorage is for the domain.... other domain cant get localstorege of other domain...